# Неправильно работает считывание

Tags: java, scanner

Есть 2 папки, в каждой из которых лежит определенное количество текстовых файлов, которые в свою очередь содержат набор вот таких строк:

> -1.0E-6   2.0E-5  0.701

Т.е. 3 числа разделенные табуляциями.(первые два числа - это коэффициенты некоторого алгоритма, последние - "качество" работы алгоритма с этими коэффициентами)
Мне же нужно отобрать те пары коэффициентов, "качество" работы алгоритма с которыми не превышает заданного числа.   
По сути мне нужно для каждой пары коэффициентов из первой папки найти такую же пару коэффициентов из другой папки и, если значения "качества" в обоих случаях меньше заданного числа, то записать это дело в файл.

Сначала считываю все данные из первой папки в список элементов TwoPar(в классе только 3 поля: 2 под коэффициенты и 3-ий под "качество"). При считывании данных из второй папки формирую объект типа TwoPar и ищу его в списке(метод equals переопределил).

Проблема в том, что, если в первом считывании считывается строчка, то при втором считывании считывается по одному числу. В чем косяк?

```
File dir1 = new File("C:\\workspace\\RTB\\Grid\\dsp8_Traf-17m");
    File dir2 = new File("C:\\workspace\\RTB\\Grid\\dsp8_Traf-6m");

    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Grid\\results - intersection - GridDSP8.txt"));
    ArrayList<TwoPar> list = new ArrayList<TwoPar>();

    String[] children1 = dir1.list();

    // Формирование списка      
    for ( int i = 0; i < children1.length; i++ ){

        File file1 = new File(dir1, children1[i]);
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(file1);

        while ( scanner1.hasNext() ){

            String line1 = scanner1.nextLine();
            String[] string1 = line1.split("\\s|=|;");

            if ( string1.length == 3 ){

                double proportional = Double.parseDouble(string1[0]);
                double integral = Double.parseDouble(string1[1]);
                double value = Double.parseDouble(string1[2]);

                TwoPar twoPar = new TwoPar(proportional, integral, value);

                list.add(twoPar);
            }
        }
        scanner1.close();
    }

    // intersection

    String[] children2 = dir2.list();

    for ( int i = 0; i < children2.length; i++ ){

        File file2 = new File(dir2, children2[i]);
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(file2);

        while( scanner2.hasNext() ){

            String line2 = scanner2.next(); // здесь лежит не строка с 3-мя числами, а только одно число
            String[] string2 = line2.split("\\s|=|;");

            if ( string2.length == 3 ){

                double proportional = Double.parseDouble(string2[0]);
                double integral = Double.parseDouble(string2[1]);
                double value = Double.parseDouble(string2[2]);

                TwoPar twoPar = new TwoPar(proportional, integral, value);

                if ( list.contains(twoPar) ){

                    int index = list.indexOf(twoPar);

                    if ( list.get(index).getValue() < 0.8 && twoPar.getValue() < 0.8 ){

                        String intersection = twoPar.getP() + "\t" + twoPar.getI() + "\t" + twoPar.getValue() + "\t" + list.get(index).getValue();
                        output.println(intersection);

                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    output.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
scanner.nextDouble()
```

для считывания даблов, а не делите строки

Comment: Спасибо, но ведь это проблемы не решает..

Comment: ну у вас во втором случае просто next, а не nextLine.

Comment: оооо.. как я обожаю такие ошибки..      
Спасибо!